# calling JavaScriptResult action methods from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to execute Java Script generated from an MVC action method, I read that JavaScriptResult type can be used for that porpouse, but my question is if it can be called from jQuery.

Controller:

```
public JavaScriptResult myActionMethods() {

     return JavaScript("alert('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "');");
}
```

JavaScript file:

```
function CallActionMethodScript() {
     //I want to execute the resulting script using jQuery...
 }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `$.getScript(someUrl)` to add a `<script>` tag that calls your action.